# Connect to a remote database for wordpress in my own hosting server

Tags: database, wp-config, localhost

Yesterday I had asked this question but it was down voted due to the rules of this forum. Anyway, this is my learning and I really thank to the moderators who down voted this as they helped me to gain the tips.

My problem is that, I have two domains in my host server **Hostgator** in the name of **damiracle.net** (*as I am not authorized to give more than one hyperlink I have to write like this way*) and **damiracle.biz**.

**The databases of damiracle.biz are frequently accessible to my employees**. I have to host a **wordpress website** in one of my directories in **damiracle.biz** (*since there are no possibilities to host that particular website in damiracle.net*). But **I need to secure the database** of that particular website in one of the directories in damiracle.biz.

In that case what I thought is that, I would host the database in damiracle.net and all the wordpress files in the damiracle.biz so that **my database remains secured** from my employees access.

In the wp-config file of the wordpress website in damiracle.biz I have mentioned in the following way:

```
define('DB_NAME', 'the_db_name_of_the DB_inside_damiracle.net');

define('DB_USER', 'the_db_user_name_of_the DB_inside_damiracle.net');

define('DB_PASSWORD', 'the_password_of_the DB_inside_damiracle.net');

define('DB_HOST', 'ip_address_of_damiracle.net');
```

Since I have to set the Remote MySQL so I had set the ip-address of damiracle.net

I had also tried setting the DB_HOST by writing damiracle.net:port No. instead of IP address

But still I face the Database connection error.

Can anyone please help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using the domain name rather than the IP address.

Comment: You also need to allow remote mysql connections in cpanel with hostgator.

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping me. My problem is solved. It was my host server issue. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

For security issues, Hostgator requires more parameters - like port, etc. - in wp-config.php to connect to a remote - non-localhost - mysql server.

Read http://support.hostgator.com/articles/cpanel/how-to-connect-to-the-mysql-database-remotely